# Debug Tizen mobile App with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, tizen

I try to use normal debugging in visual studio for Tizen mobile App with emulator Tizen, but no success. Please let me know if somebody face this problem.

Comment: Not debug your app, just run your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result? If it still has this issue, it would be not the debugging issue. You could also visit the output window to get much more detailed information, for the detailed Environment requirements, please see: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-.net-preview/getting-started/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen

Comment: When I use "start without debugging" the emulator does not run.I checked the link that you mentioned, but I have requirements for running emulator.I do not have a problem with the running emulator.I suppose that my issue is because of using Asynchronous programming and using Async and Await.

Comment: Do you get any warning or error messages during you run or debug your app? If you run a simple new Mobile App, how about the result? Actually if it still has this issue without debugging, maybe it is not the debugging issue.

Answer (score 0):

-> Create a break-point clicking on left sidebar of line of Code. It will generate a Red Circle on the left of the code line. (For Example: Line 42)

-> Press 'F5' to start debugging.

-> In the Bottom-left Click on 'Watch1' to add variables to watch.

-> Use these commands to proceed: # Step Into (F11) 
    # Step Over (F10)# Step Out (Shift+F11)

-> (Shift+F5) to stop Debugging.

[image]

[image]

You can apply same debug procedure with C# Async methods. This Documentation explains the steps in details:

[Walkthrough: Using the Debugger with Async Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155813.aspx)

Comment: I have to add this comment that I have debugging issue in my App which I use Asynchronous programming with Async and Await.

Comment: Edited the responce @ Fattaneh